# Getting Exception Failed to get Browser browser Channel in jxbrowser

Tags: java, url, jxbrowser

I 'am Using jxbrowser ,

I want to download list of urls using browser.saveWebpage

```
public class Downloader{
public Downloader(String url) {
           System.setProperty("teamdev.license.info", "true");
           LoggerProvider.getChromiumProcessLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
           Browser browser = new Browser(BrowserType.LIGHTWEIGHT);

         browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
             @Override
             public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
                 if (event.isMainFrame()){
                      String filePath = "D:\\Downloads\\index"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".html";
                      String dirPath = "D:\\Downloads\\resources";
                      event.getBrowser().saveWebPage(filePath, dirPath, SavePageType.ONLY_HTML);
                 }
             }
         });
        browser.loadURL(url);
        if(!browser.isLoading())
        {
            browser.stop());
        }
    }


public static void main(String args[])
{
      JxBrowserDemo jxBrowserDemo=null;
        String yourInputFile="D:/file.txt";
        ArrayList<String> lines=getUrls(yourInputFile); //read urls from file 

for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++)
        {  
             Thread.sleep(5000);
             jxBrowserDemo=new JxBrowserDemo(lines.get(i));
        }
}
```

}

saving pages works fine  until specific time  then it throws this exception

> Exception in thread **"main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
>   der.java:58) Caused by:
>   **com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: Failed to g
>   et Browser browserChannel 969**
>           at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.a(SourceFile:376)
>           at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.(SourceFile:200)
>           at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.(SourceFile:172)
>           at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.(SourceFile:139)
>           at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.(SourceFile:125)
>           at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.demo.JxBrowserDemo.(JxBrowserDem
>   o.java:67)
>           at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.demo.JxBrowserDemo.main(JxBrowserDemo.
>   java:143)
>           ... 5 more

please any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Failed to get Browser browserChannel 969" message most likely indicates that for some reason Chromium engine failed to create browser instance and open channel for it.
Chromium engine might have some limits for the number of browser instances created at the same time. These limits might be dependent on memory size, environment configuration, etc. As you have already created 968 browser instances without disposing them, that could be the reason of this exception.
Also please pay attention that you have a memory leak because you create new Browser instance for each URL and do not invoke the `dispose()` method after this URL Browser instance processed it's URL.

The `browser.stop();` line is unnecessary. 
Right after invoking the saveWebPage() method you should wait until web page is saved and dispose browser instance.
Please take a look at the sample code below:

```
                final int maxWaitingTime = 10000;
                final int sleepTime = 50;
                int currentWaitingTime = 0;
                File indexHTML = new File(filePath);
                File resourcesFolder = new File(dirPath);
                while (!indexHTML.exists() || !resourcesFolder.exists()) {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTime);
                    currentWaitingTime += sleepTime;
                    if (currentWaitingTime == maxWaitingTime)
                        throw new RuntimeException(new TimeoutException("The web page could not be saved."));
                }
                event.getBrowser().dispose();
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply ,but I added browser.stop to stop the created browser at all .

Comment: According to the stop() method documentation, this method cancels any pending navigation or download operation and stops any dynamic page elements, such as background sounds and animations.
This method doesn't dispose browser object and it will be existent in memory until you dispose it. This causes memory leak.
You should dispose browser instance when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: In order to run the program above properly what modification in code  should I do?